# Tag synonyms - will they actually be renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When a proposed tag synonym gets accepted, it will be ["silently remapped behind the scenes"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/).

I'm not sure if I completely understand what that means. Will it be renamed to its "master tag", eventually? Or will it be counted into badges? Will searches for the one tag also bring up answers for its synonyms?