# Should tag synonyms work for conjunctions of tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

For instance, should we have a way to specify that the tag `[javascript-performance]` is a synonym for the conjunction of `[javascript]` and `[performance]`?

Comment: +1 Good question. There is also [android-widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-widget), [android-sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sqlite) and many more android-tags with this "problem"

Comment: This post may be related: [How to choose good tags for a site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72058/how-to-choose-good-tags-for-a-site/89931#89931)

Answer (score 2):

I almost suggested that synonyms could be automatically created when they are hyphenated versions of two existing tags - but as soon as the 't' language gets going the t-sql badge would look like a synonym of t and sql.  There will be many more examples, which suggests that synonyms need to be set up by people.

I think that synonyms seem like a good idea, there is an implication for badges - but I don't think its a bad one.

If someone specifies javascript and performance as the tags, would answer upvotes then also rack up credit against the javascript-performance tag badge?  Or vice versa.

In Jonas's comment should the many android sub-tags allow someone to earn an android badge by combining the votes for android-widget and android-sqlite?

There was [this question asked last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59233/tag-synonyms-will-they-actually-be-renamed) with good points that got no answers - perhaps this is a trickier implementation than it looks at first glance.